# Multiple data objects in Ractive template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ractivejs

I am in the middle of the development of a standalone widget in jQuery and RactiveJS template. Initially the widget is opened with dynamic input form elements and these elements are populated with AJAX call. Here the email is a static field. This is the initial view for the user. When a user clicks on a button in the widget, it will validate the form and send another AJAX-POST call with validated data and show the response of the request on a `div` inside the widget template itself. If the POST call fails, some error message should be displayed in the same `div`. I have successfully implemented the initial view of the widget and validation. Below is my code:

**Template**

```
<div>  <!-- all the mustache {{}} variables are coming from the loadData() ajax call -->

    {{#partial widget-header}}
    <header>
        <div >
            <a href="#"><img alt="logo"><span>{{clientID}}</span></a> 
        </div>
    </header>
    {{/partial}} {{>widget-header}}

    <section>
        <div>
            <div>
                <form>
                    <span>Complete required fields </span> {{#partial mandatory}}
                    <em>*</em> {{/partial}} 

                    {{#each items}} 
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>{{dynamicField}}</label>{{>mandatory}}</div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="{{dynamicField}}" maxlength="20">

                            <div>{{dynamicFieldHelp}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}

                    <div >
                        <div>
                            <label>Your Email Id</label>{{>mandatory}}
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <input type="text" name="email">

                            <div>enter your email</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div >
                        <input type="button" value="Submit Form" on-click="formValidate">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
this.ractive = new Ractive({
                el: 'widgetContent',
                template: mainTemplate,
                data: function loadData() {
                     $.ajax({
                         async: false,
                         url: "https://example.com/xyz/" +employeeNo,
                         success: function (response) {
                             initialData = response.payload[0];
                         }
                     });

                     return initialData; // return the dynamic form elements in data field.
                 },

                oncomplete: function () {
                    self.center();
                }
            });
            this.ractive.on({
                formValidate: function (ev) {
                    validate the form and send AJAX-POST call then display the response data in a div - 
this is where I am stuck..
                },

            });
```

But the problem I am facing here in the second AJAX-POST call. I am not able to use a second `data` field in the ractive initialization. How can I implement this part ? If I use a second `data` field in the ractive, it will not call the first AJAX call for displaying the form elements. So my understanding is like *only one* data field can be added in the ractive initialization.

Do I need to use any advanced ractive concepts such as components to implement this part? Can someone help me on this.

note:- I haven't added `div`s for result handling in the template since I am stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want two `data` members; what you want is for your `data` to contain a separate field for the response data. Based on what you have, `data` should initially be something like:

```
  {
    items: [],
    response: 0
  }
```

I would add an `oninit` function where you do the initial AJAX call, then when you get the response do `ractive.set("items", items)` to set it. Using `set` will cause Ractive to automatically update the view with your new items.

Next, in your `formValidate` function, make your AJAX call. When the response comes back, again use `set` to notify Ractive of the change: `ractive.set("response", response)`. Add your div to the template:

```
{{#response}}
<div>{{response}}</div>
{{/}}
```